# View with a baseclass in WP7 and MVVMLight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm having multiple views in my project and want them to derive from a base class where some navigation logic is handled. This logic doesn't belong in the VM, so I've got it placed in the View.

Now when I'm trying to change the base class of the view I'm receiving the following error:

> Partial declarations of
>   'ProjectName.Results' must not specify
>   different base classes.

The only thing I've changed is:

```
public partial class Results : PhoneApplicationPage
```

to:

```
public partial class Results : BaseView
```

I can't find any other decleration of the Results class in my project. Perhaps MVVMLight generates something while building.

Is it possible to let the views derive from a base class? It should be, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your `BaseView` inherits `PhoneApplicationPage` like following:

```
public class BaseView : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    //...
}
```

After changing from:

```
public partial class Results : PhoneApplicationPage
```

To:

```
public partial class Results : BaseView
```

Also change your `XAML` from something like:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="WindowsPhonePivotApplication1.Results"
```

To:

```
<local:BaseView x:Class="WindowsPhonePivotApplication1.Results"
```

also add a xml namespace like following:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsPhonePivotApplication1"
```

Comment: Hi decyclone, I cant get the solution. In xaml, when mouse hover to <local,  it says:
The type 'local' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all assembly references has been built.

Answer (score 2):

Your Results class declaration is met in XAML as well as in code-behind file what's why you got this error. Yes It's possible to inherit views classes from base one but I think you'd better use composition to embed  your navigation logic, for instance you may create a custom control for it and insert it in all your views.

Comment: I'm reading up on Composition vs Inheritance right now. Looks interesting! Thanks for the heads up.